# Nginx reverse proxy in Docker container not loading correct website

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm running Nginx in a Docker container as a reverse proxy for a service called Appwrite: https://appwrite.io

The docker file looks like this:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/nginx
      - appwrite-certificates:/etc/ssl/private
      - ./domain2.com:/var/www
      - ./domain1.com:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - appwrite
    networks:
      - gateway
      - appwrite
```

And the Nginx config for the docker container looks like this:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
 
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/private/api.domain.com/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/api.domain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        server_name api.domain.com;
 
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_pass http://appwrite;
        }
 
        location /v1/realtime {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_pass http://appwrite-realtime;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
            proxy_send_timeout 7d;
            proxy_read_timeout 7d;
        }
    }
 
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/domain1.com;
        server_name domain1.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
 
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/domain2.com;
        server_name domain2.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I go domain api.domain.com everything works fine and loads the Appwrite dashboard, but when I navigate to either domain1.com or domain2.com it then also loads the Appwrite dashboard and not the correct www folders with the static content in them.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but I highly recommend minimizing the docker-compose.yml file generated by Appwrite as much as possible because [Appwrite's upgrade command](https://appwrite.io/docs/upgrade#install-newest-version) wipes the docker-compose.yml file. You can try to manually update the docker-compose.yml file, but that is prone to error.

In addition, I recommend using [Nginx Proxy Manager (NPM)](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) rather than manually fiddling with Nginx configs. If you go this route, you can add your domain folders to NPM's data mount and then add a proxy host for each with a  custom Nginx configuration like this:

```
location / {
  root /data/domain1.com;
}
```

For detailed instructions on how to configure NPM, you can use [this](https://dimensionquest.net/2021/02/host-static-site-on-npm/) article.

For detailed instructions on how to configure Appwrite with NPM, you can use [this](https://medium.com/@stnguyen90/how-to-run-appwrite-behind-nginx-19348ed34243) article.